# Start program from relative path

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path

In Linux when I have a folder structure like :

```
~/projects
~/bin
```

I could go to projects and start whatever program is in bin with

`../bin/binary_to_launch`

In Windows when I try the same thing, I get

`'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Is there a way to start program from relative path in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses backslashes (`\`) instead of slashes (`/`). Try

```
..\bin\binary_to_launch
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using forward slashes (`/`) as path separators. Switch to backward ones (`\`) and the program will start as expected.

In Windows, both slash types can generally be used interchangeably. CMD.EXE is an exception to this, since most console programs use forward slashes to denote command switches.

Comment: Se prolava gia ena lepto :)